# Scrolling text box that cannot be user-edited?

Tags: microsoft-excel, activex

I'm making a dashboard for an Excel sheet, and I want to have a way to output messages to the user.  These messages may be fairly lengthy, and I don't want this output console to take up too much space on the page, so ideally I'd like to have a small window that can be scrolled up and down.  I do not want the user to be able to edit the output content.

I tried using an ActiveX text box for this.  But when the text box is disabled to prevent user editing, the scroll bar is disabled as well.  I also tried a label, but the label doesn't have a scroll bar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is not the `ENABLED` property, but the `LOCKED` property.

By locking your edit-box, you will prohibit editing, while allowing scrolling.

You might want to use a different coloring however, because it is counterintuitive, if it still looks like a regular edit-box.